# Unable to locate executable file: 'bash'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH

Tags: bash, azure-devops

I go the following error while print group variable in azure DevOps both yaml and classic using MS hosted agent

```
##[error]Unable to locate executable file: 'bash'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable.
```

The yml code below

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
- group: myvargroup

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: "Test"
    jobs:
      - job: 
        steps:
        - script: echo $(fname)
          displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

The job parameter below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWn2y.jpg)

Error screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8UtX.png)

Comment: Please specify your question.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your sample, it works well now. There is a recently event of availability degradation of Azure DevOps, which could affected these services, and it has been resolved. If you want to know more information, please click [here](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/239404330). You can try again to see if the problem still exists.

[image]